# Angular Click Event Triggered Second Click Only

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following html/TS in Angular that doesn't perform my (click) action until the
second click. I tried commenting out the setTimeout logic to see if that was causing any issues but still had the same problem. I was able to fix it but defaulting `priceFocused = true;` but that's not an option. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

My goal is to display a div of suggestions that a user can click on to set the value on the model. If the user clicks outside of the input then the suggestions would disappear, if a user clicks on a suggestion it should set the value and disappear.

```
<div class="input-field width-100">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="number" class="w-100" value="0.00" name="price"
        (focus)="priceFocused = true" (blur)="priceFieldBlur()"
        [(ngModel)]="currentInventory.price" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange()">
    <div class="suggestions suggestions-wider" *ngIf="priceFocused">
        <ul>
            <ng-container *ngIf="currentInventory.card.tcgplayer.prices != null">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let price of formatPriceData()">
                    <li class="card-choice" *ngIf="price != null"
                        (click)="currentInventory.price=price[1]">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-8">
                                {{price[0]}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                ${{price[1]}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant TS:

```
  public priceFocused: boolean = false;

  priceFieldBlur() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.priceFocused = false;
    }, 500); // Delay of 500 milliseconds (half second)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some pretty odd things here.  You have a `blur` event that runs your `priceFieldBlur()` function.  This will run when the input loses focus.

Then your `click` event is just setting a property.  Clicking on this has absolutely nothing to do with the `priceFieldBlur()` event you are adding the delay to.

In general you should avoid writing logic and setting values inside your HTML template.  Call methods and set your property values in the class.

Instead, I think you should re-write it as follows to fix some of these issues

```html
<div class="input-field width-100">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="number" class="w-100" value="0.00" name="price"
        (focus)="priceFieldFocus()" (blur)="priceFieldBlur()"
        [(ngModel)]="currentInventory.price" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange()">
    <div class="suggestions suggestions-wider" *ngIf="priceFocused">
        <ul>
            <ng-container *ngIf="currentInventory.card.tcgplayer.prices != null">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let price of formatPriceData()">
                    <li class="card-choice" *ngIf="price != null"
                        (click)="setCurrentInventoryPrice(price)">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-8">
                                {{price[0]}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                ${{price[1]}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```ts
public priceFocused: boolean = false;

priceFieldFocus() {
  this.priceFocused = true;
}

priceFieldBlur() {
  this.priceFocused = false;
}

setCurrentInventoryPrice(price){
  currentInventory.price = price[1];
}
```

However, I see a potential problem here.  You have a field that sets `priceFocused` based on when the field is focused or not. When it is focused you show the stuff below which has a click event.  In order to click on that you have to remove focus from the input element, which would then hide the element you are trying to click on.  I don't what what your goal is here, but this seems broken and feels like it will be frustrating to use.

Comment: My goal is to display a div of suggestions that a user can click on to set the value on the model. If the user clicks outside of the input then the suggestions would disappear, if a user clicks on a suggestion it should set the value and disappear. Would there be a better way to do this through angular?

Comment: Unfortunately this results in my suggestions box closing before the click can register

Comment: What if you removed the `blur` event and instead made it when a click event happens outside of the `.input-field` element.